# Retrieve user property from Firebase Analytics

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I am currently setting Firebase Analytics properties like gender and usernames as follows:

```
firebaseAnalytics.setUserProperty("username", /*someusername*/);
```

After successfully setting them I want to be able to receive them at some other point inside my application. Somehow similar to the Firebase Database.

Is this possible? I have not found any explanation in the Firebase documentation.

Comment: what have you tried? do you use firebase authentication to authenticate your user?

Comment: Yeah i added email and password by firebase authentication

Comment: And added other data like username,age,gender in analytis properties @Wilik

Comment: What code should I add then? I just want to know how can I retieve data from Firebase User Properties :( @hotrod

Comment: looks like it's not possible to retrieve Firebase Analytics user properties, the best way that you can do is to store those properties to Firebase Database for each user

Comment: Ohk now look at the single line code.. I want to retrieve that data @hotrod

Comment: @hotrod well, he mentioned it in his second comment :)

Comment: Thanx I will try @Wilik

Comment: I edited the question to better suit what you actually meant. Hope this helps other people answering it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently, it is not possible to retrieve Firebase Analytics User Property.

The best way you can do is to also store those properties to Firebase Database for each user. The database structure should look something like this

```
{
    "users": {
        "<uid>": {
            "username": "someusername",
            "gender": "M",
            "birthDate": 758634444000
        }
    }
}
```

The `uid` is retrieved from `FirebaseUser.getUid()`

Hope this helps :)